# How do I uninstall python3.6 on ubuntu when it is located on /usr/local/bin/python3.6

Tags: python, ubuntu

So my default version of python3 is 3.7.5

```
which python3

/usr/bin/python3
```

Now my python3.6 is installed in:

```
which python3.6

/usr/local/bin/python3.6
```

If I try to uninstall it like so:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.6

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'python3.6-2to3' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.6-stdlib' for regex 'python3.6'
Note, selecting 'python3.6-rpy2' for regex 'python3.6'
Package 'libpython3.6-stdlib' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python3.6-2to3' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
```

And if like so:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge /usr/local/bin/python3.6

Reading package lists... Done
E: Unsupported file /usr/local/bin/python3.6 given on commandline
```

Comment: check `apt search python3` to see if it is on list. Maybe you will have to simply delete folder.

Comment: Also try running `dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/python3.6` to determine which package provides that file

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/local` is outside the control of `apt` completely. Without knowing how you installed this binary in the first place, we can't know what else might need removing (in particular, there is probably a fairly large library hierarchy somewhere like `/usr/local/lib/python3.6` which should also be purged). Simply `sudo rm` will remove the binary, but if you used some sort of management system to install it there, you will probably confuse that system by doing things behind its back.

A common way to install things locally is from source; if you used `make install` then the same `Makefile` probably also supports `make uninstall`.